# how do I highlight the current line in QScintilla

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscintilla

I want to highlight the current line (the line the caret is in, similar to Notepad++) in QScintilla. Searching the interwebs gave nothing at all. Am I missing something obvious?

```py
qscintillaWidget = QsciScintilla(parent = self)
qscintillaWidget.highlightCurrentLine(True)  # <- something like this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable and then choose a color.

```
qscintillaWidget.setCaretLineVisible(True)
qscintillaWidget.setCaretLineBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor('lightblue'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to highlight a specific line in QScintilla is to use Indicators:
https://qscintilla.com/#clickable_text/indicators

```
DEFAULT_INDICATOR_ID = 1
self.__editor.indicatorDefine(QsciScintilla.FullBoxIndicator, DEFAULT_INDICATOR_ID)
self.__editor.fillIndicatorRange(line_number, 0, line_number+1, 0, DEFAULT_INDICATOR_ID)
```